# How can I replace a pressure gauge on a well pump?

Tags: well-pump

The gauge on my well pump is shot (reads 0, even when there is good pressure).  I've purchased a replacement, so what are the steps I should follow to replace it?

Comment: This may be to do with your other [question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/14364/5918), why is the gauge broken in the first place? Once you give us some more info about the pump we may be able to help but you should fix the problem before replacing the pressure gauge

Comment: @UNECS The gauge was broken when I bought the house a couple months ago.  It just rose to the top of the list of fix.  The pump running constantly is new.

Answer (score 4):

1. Turn off the power to the pump.
2. Turn off the feed to the house (there should be a valve between the pressure tank and rest of house). This is simply to make the next step easier.
3. Drain any water from the pipes where the pressure switch is screwed in. Usually there is a sed valve.
4. Unscrew the existing gauge.
5. Check the T where the gauge was screwed in for build-up/blockage. This may be what messed up the existing gauge in the first place. If there's any, clear it out as much as possible.
6. Use teflon tape or pipe dope on the threads, and screw in the new gauge.
7. Turn everything back on.

[image]

Comment: 4A - get same type gauge (pressure range, fitting size)

Comment: An 8" crescent wrench will be large enough to remove the gauge. Only put force on the square part just below the gauge body don't twist on the gauge body or housing or it can mess up the gauge. Gauges break all the time , no need to try and troubleshoot a broken gauge.