# How do I fix a Well Pump that is on Constantly?

Tags: well-pump

Recently my well pump started running 24/7.  What might be wrong, and what are the steps I would take to fix the issue?

Comment: pressure switch may be broken or stuck, model and type would be handy or non return is not functioning but this is less likely

Comment: The pressure gauge is essential for diagnosis, so fix that first. There is possibly a problem with your pressure switch, your pump may not be working correctly and generating enough pressure, or there could be a leak in the line somewhere. Once you fix the pressure gauge, close the valve to the rest of the house and update this post to say what's happening with the gauge. If it's getting higher than 60psi (or whatever the setpoint is if you know it) and not shutting off, your pressure switch is either jammed or just adjusted too high.

Comment: The pump burnt it self out, but we went ahead and replaced everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's trouble with the pressure tank.  You are right to be concerned.  Its bad for the pump to be running constantly.

Is there a pressure gauge? What does it read?   Is the P-Tank full of water?

It could be simply needs to be charged with air compressor.  When was last time?

Comment: The pressure gauge is broken, I have another question for replacing it.  No idea how long ago the tank was charged.

Comment: I'd recommend borrow a compressor and try charging it.  A replacement PTank is about a grand, a well pump is tenfold. Could prolly get plumber to charge it and replace the gauge for couple hundred.

Comment: It does not sound like a problem with the pressure tank to me. When the pre-charge is too low, bladder broken, or the tank is water-logged, you get rapid cycling as you use the water (since there is no buffer). I am not sure if the tank is 100% full of water what will happen, as 1) I've never had a pressure switch hooked up to a pump without a pressure tank, and 2) In many summers of working on water systems, I've *never* seen a pressure tank with absolutely NO air. Even a tiny amount of air will provide pressure resistance needed to make it at least rapid-cycle.

Comment: @Trout Just FYI Your cost scale is a little off.  We heard $300 for a tank, and ~$1000 for a pump, installed.  Probably commercial stuff costs in the range you're talking about.

Comment: Where are you located that people work for so little?

I replaced my PTank for a grand.  Getting my cost scale from experience.

Comment: @C.Ross - I'm with you. I've bought 2-3 well pumps as they have worn out over the years and NEVER paid more than $300 for any of them.